# Is there a photo capture app built into Windows10 or Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, adobe-photoshop, photos

My windows laptop has a camera built-in. Can I use it to grab a photo. Does windows come with an app to capture a photo like "Photo Capture" on mac? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use it to grab a photo.

Yes

> Does windows come with an app to capture a photo like "Photo Capture" on mac?

Windows 10 has the [Camera UWP](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/windows-camera/9wzdncrfjbbg) application which is installed by default on all Windows 10 OEM devices.

Comment: Windows 7 doesn’t have a built-in Camera application.  Only third-party software exists.  Questions seeking software recommendations are strictly not within scope here at Superuser which is the reason I won’t be recommending any third-party software.